# How do i retrieve a NetSuite contact that is associated with a record

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

In NetSuite when editing a record i have a button that needs to be able to grab all of the contacts first names, last names, email, and possibly role so that i can attach that to other code i have already written. I cannot seem to figure out how to extract contacts associated with a record.

I have retrieved the record from the 'N/record' module and got the Sublist "contact" using the sublistId "contact" however the only method with the Sublist is to getColumn and it requires an options.fieldId which i don't have or know how to find and even if i did the object that it would return (column object) does not appear to have the values that i would like.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/currentRecord','N/record'],function(context, recordKeeper){
    var options = {type:context.get().type, id:context.get().id, isDynamic:context.get().isDynamic};
    var record = recordKeeper.load(options);

    function TestButtonClick(){
        var contactSublist = record.getSublist({sublistId:"contact"});
        //Need to get the contact information here
        alert(JSON.stringify(contactSublist));//{"id":"contact","type":"staticlist","isChanged":false,"isDisplay":true}
    }

    function pageInit(context){
        //some code
    }

    var exports = {};
    exports.TestButtonClick = TestButtonClick;
    exports.pageInit = pageInit;

    return exports;
});

**EDIT 2**
NetSuite Fields
+customer
+customer - Address
-customer Contact
   -customer Contact 1
       Alt. Email
       Assist. Phone
       Assistant
       Attached Role
       Catagory
       Comments
       Contact (Auto-Filled)
       Contact Company
       Customer ID/Project
       Email
       Externalid
       Fax
       First Name
       Global subscription Status
       Home Phone
       Image
       Inactive
       Job Title
       Last Name
```

My contactSublist gives me an object as i would expect however from this contact sublist i am unsure how to retrieve the contacts associated with the record or if i am even taking the right path to get that information.

**EDIT:**
I have tried record.getLineCount({sublistid: "contact"})
record.getSublistValue({sublistId: "contact", fieldId: ,line: })
and record.getSublistText({sublistId: "contact", fieldId: ,line: })
however i am throwing exceptions as if my contacts don't exist even though i see them on screen. This is the exception message
"You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist."

**EDIT 2**

I don't know how to attach a screenshot here if its possible so here is a text visual of it, look in the code section because i could not get the layout to look good here, only in the code section would it keep my formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the contact information, you should iterate through the contact sublist. First get the count of the sublist using `record.getLineCount({sublistid: "contact"})`. Then you can get the information of each sublist field/column by using `record.getSublistValue({sublistId: "contact", fieldId: <field>,line: <index>})` in a loop, usually a for loop.

Comment: i must still be missing something. I did 
var record.getSublist({sublistId:"contact"});
which gave me an object that looks like this 
"{"id":"contact","type":"staticlist","isChanged":false,"isDisplay":true}"
however when i do record.getLineCount({sublistId:"contact"}) as you suggested i get a line count of 0. When i scroll to the bottom of my form i click contact -> contacts and i have myself added as a contact. Im starting to think the issue may not be with the code but may be with the setup of the form, but i am unsure.

Comment: `record.getSublist` is used to get the sublist information/setting not the data.  This is why you are getting the object.  It I understood your question, you wanted to get the data of the columns in the contact sublist, if I am right you need to use `record.getSublistValue` or `record.getSublistText`.

Comment: still no luck :( i have read the documentation on those method calls and they look like what i need however i keep getting script exceptions for them, i have added it to the question above in the edit section

Comment: You need to provide the fieldId and the line index of the contact line you are trying to get. At least I don't see it in your edit.

Comment: Sorry i left the value for fieldId and index blank in my edit. I have been filling them out using the information in the contacts section of the records browser. I have tried most of the "internal IDs" however with no luck. some of the ID's i have used include email, entityid, firstname, lastname, mobilephone, officephone, phone, title but they all return the same message. "You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist."

Comment: I am unsure why i am getting this message as i can see the contacts on screen in the record. i don't know if this will help but i was just shown what appears to be a layout of the page (i do not know the workings of creating the forms i only have access to the api's) In the screenshot i was provided it appears the actual contacts are in a "contacts 1" that is inside of a "contacts" however when i tried to access the "contacts 1" sublisting i was unsuccessful.

Comment: I added a 2nd edit with the layout as i dont know if/how i can attach the screenshot here. Thank you for all of your help by the way.

Comment: What values have you used for the line parameter?  The error you get usually happens because the line value is out of bounds,e.g. using 2 when there is only 1 line.

Comment: For the line ive been using 0. I was assuming that the content would begin at index 0.

Comment: Based on what you have given to me, you are doing everything right. Not sure why it is not working.